# Way to set all fields of a base class implicitely

Tags: java

I have a base class and a class that extends it. The derivate class is generally only a wrapper that adds another attribute. I want to initialize the derivate class by giving it base classe in a builder method.

```
@Data //this just generates getters/setters
public class AWrapper extends Base {

  private String myNewAttribute;

  public static AWrapper fromBase(Base base){
    AWrapper result = new AWrapper();

    // this is what I would like to ommit
    this.setSomeAttributeFromBase(base.getSomeAttributeFromBase());
    // .... a lot more handwritten get/set

    return result;
  }

}
```

I would like to not to write the middle part where all the manual set/get is done because that would mean that if a field in the base class is added/deleted I would have to touch the derived class.

I thought about fetching all methods starting with "get" but getters for bools start with "is" normally, and it seems to be a flaky way anyway. Is there a good pattern for this?

Comment: You should be able to use Apache's `BeanUtils#copyProperties`.

Comment: What about creating a protected copy constructor for the base class?

Comment: Thanks for the hints, @493msi not sure what you mean by protected copy constructor. I cannot touch the Base class code since it's generated.

Comment: @daniu the beanutils method might work. I'll try it thanks.